# Python 2.7 - Outlook Win32com.client Can't get senders actual email address from .msg

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com

How can I get the senders email address from a .MSG file using the win32com.client module in python?

This is what I have so far:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

for path, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in files:
        filename_no_ext, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext.lower() in ['.msg']:

            try:
                msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(path), filename))
            except Exception as x:
                print >>sys.stderr, filename
                print >>sys.stderr, x
                continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [MailItem.SenderEmailAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.senderemailaddress) property.